# Conditional summarise() count with 2 columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to count the number of observations by using 2 conditions from different rows after grouping. I'll use the `starwars` data frame as an example.

```
name     height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex   gender homeworld species films vehicles
   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <lis> <list>  
 1 Luke Sk…    172    77 blond      fair       blue            19   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>   
 2 C-3PO       167    75 NA         gold       yellow         112   none  mascu… Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>   
 3 R2-D2        96    32 NA         white, bl… red             33   none  mascu… Naboo     Droid   <chr> <chr>   
 4 Darth V…    202   136 none       white      yellow          41.9 male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>   
 5 Leia Or…    150    49 brown      light      brown           19   fema… femin… Alderaan  Human   <chr> <chr>   
 6 Owen La…    178   120 brown, gr… light      blue            52   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>   
 7 Beru Wh…    165    75 brown      light      blue            47   fema… femin… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>   
 8 R5-D4        97    32 NA         white, red red             NA   none  mascu… Tatooine  Droid   <chr> <chr>   
 9 Biggs D…    183    84 black      light      brown           24   male  mascu… Tatooine  Human   <chr> <chr>   
10 Obi-Wan…    182    77 auburn, w… fair       blue-gray       57   male  mascu… Stewjon   Human   <chr> <chr>
```

My intention is to get a the means and standard deviation after grouping by sex as well as a single column which is the count of females higher than 100, males higher than 120, hermaphroditic characters higher than 110, no-sex characters higher than 100 and NAs for sex higher than 50.

I thought about filtering first by sex, doing the calculations separately and then joining all the data together again. But I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do that in a single data frame.

I thought of something as:

```
starwars %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean_height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE),
            sd_heigt = sd(height, na.rm = TRUE),
            higher_characters =
              if(sex == "female")        {count(height > 100)},
              if(sex == "male")          {count(height > 120)},
              if(sex == "hermaphroditic"){count(height > 110)},
              if(sex == "none")          {count(height > 100)},
              if(is.na(sex))             {count(height >  50)}
            )
```

But I get an Error and this is not working. I haven't used `if` in dplyr much, so I'm not sure if I am using it correctly or if it's just that this is not the way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cur_group` and `switch` and (for convenience) a small custom function you could do:

```r
n_condition <- function(group, x) {
  switch(group,
         "female" = sum(x > 100, na.rm = TRUE),
         "male" = sum(x > 120, na.rm = TRUE),
         "hermaphroditic" = sum(x > 110, na.rm = TRUE),
         "none" = sum(x > 100, na.rm = TRUE),
         sum(x > 50, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
}

library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean_height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE),
            sd_heigt = sd(height, na.rm = TRUE),
            higher_characters = n_condition(cur_group()$sex, height))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   sex            mean_height sd_heigt higher_characters
#>   <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>             <int>
#> 1 female                169.    15.3                 15
#> 2 hermaphroditic        175     NA                    1
#> 3 male                  179.    36.0                 52
#> 4 none                  131.    49.1                  2
#> 5 <NA>                  181.     2.89                 3
```

Comment: Thank you, that reall does the job. But, why the ```$sex``` in ```cur_group()``` inside the call of ```n_condition```?

Comment: `cur_group` returns a tibble with (in your case) one column "sex". Hence we have to use `$sex` to get the current group category as a vector.

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference. Thank you!